# Prevent hover triggering for div in raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael, jquery-events

I need to draw custom dom tooltip over raphael svg element. How to prevent event triggering mouseleave for element, when you hover tooltip?

Check this example:

```
$(c.node).mouseenter(function(){
    tipText = 'text';
    tip.show();
    over = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    tip.hide();
    over = false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QK7hw/707/

Comment: In fiddle try to move mouse to bottom right.

Comment: ok so wat is meant to happen if i move it there?

Comment: cause nothing is happening in the fiddle

Comment: Tooltip must no blinking(show/hide).

Comment: Move mouse over circle. And move to right bottom corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the style

```
pointer-events: none;
```

To the tooltip, that should stop the odd hover flashing.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QK7hw/708/)